# Why does my jQuery animation margin not reset to the original point upon re-execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var increasingMargin = 350;
$(".pop-out-image").click(function(){
if(popImage == 0) {
    popImage = 1;
    $(".pop-out-image").each(function(){
        $(this).animate({marginTop: increasingMargin});
            increasingMargin+=250;
    });
}
else{
    popImage = 0;
    $(".pop-out-image").each(function(){
        $(this).animate({marginTop: increasingMargin});
        increasingMargin -= 250;
    });
}
});
```

[How it should reset too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqr78.png)

It's a simple concept, you click the div and it shows the 3 images as intended, however the next step is zipping them back to their original point, i figured i could just reverse the margin, but now i'm unsure on how to proceed. Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uswmfyru/2/

It works as intended as for displaying the images, however any help with getting them back to their start point would be awesome!

I'm probably being dumb here.